# Is this a counterexample to Landauer's principle?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, landauers-principle

Landauer's principle states that if I have a physical system with two possible states, and that system begins in an unknown state, then putting the system into a known state takes the addition of at least $ k T \ln (2) $ Joules to the system.

Counterexample: suppose I have one particle in a box that can be separated in half by a massless and frictionless piston, just like the setup of Szilard's engine. The particle has kinetic energy E, and starts in the box without a divide. I decide that I want to put the particle in the left side. I close the divide at a random time, and measure the particle (which I understand can be done with an arbitrarily small amount of energy) to see if it's on the left. If it is: success. If it's not remove the barrier, wait, and close it and check again. Repeat until the particle is measured to be on the left.

I think we can all agree that I didn't add or subtract any (significant amount of) energy during this process, so this seems to contradict Laudauer's principle.

Answer (score 4):

Landauer's principle is about the energy cost of *erasing* information. When you check where the particle is, you presumably do so using a detector that now reads "left" or "right". You can indeed use this information to put the particle in the left side of the box without much energy cost, but now to finish the job you have to erase the bit of information in your detector. In other words, you haven't actually done any erasure at all; you've merely moved the bit from one place to another.